# Stack Overflow is writing comments in my name to myself

Tags: feature-request, comments, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

I posted a question at [Force Google Sheet SPLIT to create strings, not numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59423523/force-google-sheet-split-to-create-strings-not-numbers) but later found out that it was already answered somewhere else.

I then wanted to close my question and created a link to the duplicate but it was still open because it needed close votes from other people.

Later I got comments why I am posting comments to myself, which I didn't do and found out that Stack Overflow seems to automatically generate comments when creating close votes, which does not make sense when one is the person asking the question.

I propose that question askers can close their own questions for duplicates without requiring additional votes and that the system does not send me comments to myself in my own name.

P.S.: The comment is gone now that I clicked on "yes" for the question "does this solve your problem" which it obviously does because I added it in the first place.

[image: screenshot of all comments on original question]

Comment: The "possible duplicate..." comment is the only auto-generated one when voting to close and is only left by the person who cast the first vote or flag.  And it is automatically deleted when the question is closed.  This is an odd corner case that probably is very rare when you cast the first duplicate vote on your own question.  Given you can close your own question by clicking "Yes" as you found, the fact that casting the duplicate close vote on your own question doesn't automatically assume that you would click "Yes" and close the question is probably the real feature request here.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Yes that would have the same effect, either not requiring additional votes or internally solving that by directly showing the option and clicking yes on it. The problem with the way it is now is that the option does not appear right away which left enough time for another user to get confused by the comment.

Comment: I observe this confusing behavior in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59393131/1997232). OP was trying to close own question, but it took a while until `Community` finally handles it (it was awaiting for an additional "Yes" from OP). During this *short time* anyone can read very stupid auto-comment where OP seems to be asking himself "Does this solves your problem ... ?". I was LOLed, but honestly it's not funny.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Automatic comments are also posted when the close-vote is for a custom reason. The automatic comments from custom close reasons are not deleted when the question is closed.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks, I think it would be better if that `auto-generated` be mentioned on the comment.